# matrix transpose proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that if an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ satisfies $A^T=-A$, then $x^TAx=0$ for any $n\times 1$ vector $x$.

My attempt: Since matrix transpose won't affect the diagonal entries, so matrix $A$ has only zeros on its diagonal.

Then I tried to write $x$ in the form of $\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}$ and $A$ in the form of $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n}\\
a_{21} & 0 & \cdots & \cdots \\
\vdots &\ddots &\ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \cdots & 0
\end{pmatrix}$ and multiply them in this form, but it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: See what indices of $x$ multiply $a_{ij}$, and then see what indices of $x$ multiply $a_{ji}$.

Comment: What's the transpose of $x^TAx$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $(x^TAx)^T=x^TA^Tx=-x^TAx$. will that help?

Comment: @fcc $x^\top Ax$ is a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can see is that $x^TAx$ is of type $(1\times1)$, hence symmetric, i.e.,

$$(x^TAx)^T = x^TAx.$$
On the other hand we have
$$x^TA^Tx= x^TAx.$$

From $A^T=-A$ we get $$-x^TAx = x^TAx\iff 2x^TAx =0\iff x^TAx=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$x^TA^Tx=\sum_{i,j}x_i(A^T)_{ij}x_j=\sum_{i,j}x_iA_{ji}x_j=\sum_{i,j}x_jA_{ji}x_i=x^TAx$$
But we also have that
$$x^TA^Tx=\sum_{i,j}x_i(-A)_{ij}x_j=-x^TAx$$
So
$$x^TAx=-x^TAx$$
So it must be $0$.

Comment: for $x_j$ and $x_i$, do you mean entries of the vector? Why does $x_jA_{ji}x_i=xAx$?

Comment: @fcc I was using einstein notation. But I will add the $\sum$ signs.